# Accessing Derived functions in polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class

I think the easiest way to explain my problem is to show a simplistic example of what I am trying to do.

I am using a library which has a base class as an example take the following.

```
class base {
     void function();
}
```

Now the derived classes are apart of the library and all contain the same function.

```
class derived1 : public base {
     void derivedFunction();
}

class derived2 : public base {
     void derivedFuction();
}
```

In the function that I created I define a couple of derived classes and I build a struct containing the base class. I then set a few values in an array and use polymorphism and set the value of thisClass as a derived class.

```
void runMe() {

     derived1 *thisDerivedClass = new derived1;
     derived2 *thatDerivedClass = new derived2;

     struct data {
          const char * name;
          int someInt;
          base thisClass;
          } dataSets [] = {
              {"test1", 0, thisDerivedClass},
              {"test2", 1, thatDerivedClass}
          };
```

When I try to call a function from the derived obviously it does not work. What I am trying to figure out is how to get this to work. Virtual classes do not make sense as I would have to change a lot. The other way I know how to do it is through dynamic and static typing, which does not make sense for this situation.

```
     const int count = sizeof(dataSets) / sizeof(data);

     for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          dataSets[i].thisClass->derivedFuction();
     }
}
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Virtual classes?  Looks like you need virtual *functions*, not classes.  Also, your struct has a `base` object.  Shouldn't that be `base*`?

Comment: My mistake, yes and yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is what polymorphism and virtual functions were invented for. Declare a virtual function in the base class, then reimplement it in the derived classes. Then your call to `base::function()` will resolve to the correct derived class function automatically.

Comment: I agree, I think what I will do is restructure my code to work with the framework I am using.